# Java android coordinator layouts LinearLayout beetween two layouts

Tags: java, android

Can I add inside two layouts a LinearLayout  ? I know that is a floating Action Button but I want to put a LinearLayout   and I want to create this :

[image]

And This what I want to set inside two layouts is in LinearLayout and in android.support.design.widget.TabLayout

This is my xml code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/rel"
    android:background="#fff"
    tools:context="pl.smok.ui.activity.MainActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/top_bar_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/top_bar_container">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize">

            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/view_pager"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            app:tabGravity="center"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="#fff"
            app:tabBackground="@drawable/tab_color_selector"
            app:tabMode="scrollable"
            app:tabTextAppearance="@style/MyCustomTextAppearance" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Post your code here

Comment: @SushobhNadiger I edit my post and put my xml file

Comment: Where do you want to add a layout?

Comment: @SushobhNadiger inside TabLayout id=tab_layout and FrameLayout id=top_bar_container

Comment: You cannot ad a layout inside tab layout in xml , you can add a layout inside frame layout.

Comment: @SushobhNadiger Ok but can I So that the part was in the frame layout and in the new layout?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144330/discussion-between-pawel-o-and-sushobh-nadiger).

Answer (score -1):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

   >
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/rel"
    android:background="#fff"
  >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/top_bar_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/top_bar_container">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize">

            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/view_pager"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            app:tabGravity="center"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="#fff"
            app:tabBackground="@drawable/tab_color_selector"
            app:tabMode="scrollable"
            app:tabTextAppearance="@style/MyCustomTextAppearance" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Coordinator layot will always be root layout.

Comment: Ok but How I can add a one layot  So that the part was in the frame layout and in the new layout?